# overriding a method from a class with a private variable

Tags: java

If I have a class that can't be changed (inside a jar), 
Ex.

```
public class AA implements A{
  private String s = "foo";
  public String getValue() { return s; }
}
```

what would be a good way to override that getValue() method? 
My way has been recopying the class. Ex.

```
public class AB implements A{
  private String s = "foo";
  public String getValue() { return s + "bar"; }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No matter what you do, you cant get access to the private variable (without reflection).  If you needs its value, invoke the superclass's getter in your getter, to get the value, then manipulate it as you will.  You can invoke the superclass's method by doing

`super.getValue();`

inside your `getValue` implementation.

Given your update

```
public class AB extends AA {
  public String getValue() { 
      String superS = super.getValue();
      return superS + "bar"; 
  }
}
```

Note the following

1) Im using `extends` which you do not. `extends` is for extending a class, `implements` is for implementing an interface.
2) Im not shadowing `s`.  I'm leaving that in the super class.  I just use the super's `getValue` in conjunction what the decoration you specified.

Comment: thanx, but be sure the option presented by @GETah is not what you want.  It's an equally valid solution.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of fixing this:

**1)** Using inheritance.

```
public B extends A{
    public String getValue(){
     String s = super.getValue();
     // do something with s
     return s;
  }
}
```

This will work fine but users can still cast `B` to `A` as `B` inherits from `A`. Which means that you can still access `A.getValue()` from a class `B` and that's not what you want.

**2)** The other solution is to use the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

```
public B {
  private A a = new A();
  public String getValue(){
     String s = a.getValue();
     // do something with s
     return s;
  }
}
```

This way, `B` uses `A` and hides it. No casts of `B` to `A` will be possible and no calls to `A.getValue()` would be available.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the other option.  However, this is NOT the adapter pattern.  It's composition (vs inheritance).  For it to be the adapter pattern, you would need to change the interface.  Here the interface (method signature) has not changed.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Thank you :) Just looked back to my GoF book and it confirms that this is a modified version of the adapter pattern. The adapter pattern is also called composition pattern or wrapper pattern it that what you mean?

Comment: your option 2 is composition; one object contains an instance to another, instead of extending the class.  I would not call that the Adaptor pattern.  My copy of GoF says use adaptor when 'its interface does not match the one you need (p140, first option under applicability)'.  In this case, it's not a problem.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Yes that is true, this is somehow a modified adapter pattern as there are no interfaces involved but you are right in saying that it is a composition too.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what **Encapsulations** are for... Your example points at Design principle named as **OCP (Open Closed Principle).**

That means **Classes are open for extension, and not for modifications.** You can use the jars methods to access its private variables, but cannot modify it in a illegal way.

You can **access the private variable in the super-class, by only accessing the super-class's getter method.**